# Problems in adding linux defender extension in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform

Note: Cross-posted in Hashicorp forum: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/problems-in-adding-linux-defender-extension-in-azure/53949

I am trying to add an MS defender extension to a Linux VM (rockylinux 8.x) in Azure. Here is my terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "linux_defender" {
  name                        = "linux_defender"
  virtual_machine_id          = azurerm_virtual_machine.linuxvm[0].id 
  auto_upgrade_minor_version  = "true"
  publisher                   = "Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers"
  type                        = "MDE.Linux"
  type_handler_version        = "1.0"
}
```

When I execute it, I am getting the following error:

```
 Error: Code="VMExtensionHandlerNonTransientError" Message="The handler for VM extension type 'Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers.MDE.Linux' has reported terminal failure for VM extension 'linux_defender' with error message: '[ExtensionOperationError] Non-zero exit code: 53, /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers.MDE.Linux-1.0.3.7/PythonRunner.sh src/MdeExtensionHandler.py enable\n[stdout]\nPython 3.6.8\n\n\n[stderr]\n2023-05-18 16:20:02,212, INFO - Start executing handler action: enable\n2023-05-18 16:20:02,213, ERROR - Failed to retrieve configuration. Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\n'.\r\n    \r\n'Enable handler for the extension failed. More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionlinuxtroubleshoot'"
│ 
│   with module.virtual_machines["d-rhub-vm0"].azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.linux_defender[0],
```

Has anyone been successful to add the defender extensions for servers in Azure for Redhat flavored Linux?
I was not sure whether Defender gets preloaded in Linux from Azure marketplace image?

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-cloud/microsoft-defender-for-endpoint-for-linux-and-microsoft-defender/ba-p/3702077

Answer (score 0):

Check the following  code:

**Enable Azure defender** : source code from: [Microsoft defender terraform-Github](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft-Defender-for-Cloud/blob/main/Terraform/Deploy%20Microsoft%20Defender%20for%20Cloud/main.tf)

**code**:

> ```
> resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "assgn_asb" {
>   name                 = "azuresecuritybenchmark"
>   display_name         = "Azure Security Benchmark"
>   policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8"
>   subscription_id      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
> }
>
>   ....
> resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "mdc_servers" {
>   tier          = "Standard"
>   resource_type = "VirtualMachines"
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_security_center_setting" "setting_mcas" {
>   setting_name = "MCAS"
>   enabled      = false
> }
>
>
>
> resource "azurerm_security_center_setting" "setting_mde" {
>   setting_name = "WDATP"
>   enabled      = true
> }
> ```

Here the following enables loganalytics agents or azure monitor agents.

> ```
> resource "azurerm_security_center_auto_provisioning" "auto-provisioning" {
>   auto_provision = "On"
> }
> ```

create a log analytic workspace to store the logs of these.

> ```
> resource "azurerm_security_center_workspace" "myloga_workspace" {
>   scope        = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
>   workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.myloga_workspace.id
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment" "auto-provisioning" {
>   name                 = "mdc-va-autoprovisioning"
>   display_name         = "Machines to receive a vulnerability assessment provider"
>   policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/13ce0167-8ca6-4048-8e6b-f996402e3c1b"
>   subscription_id      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
>   identity {
>     type = "SystemAssigned"
>   }
>   location = "West US2"
>   parameters =..
>
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "auto-provrole" {
>   scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
>   role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/fb1c8493-542b-48eb-b624-b4c8fea62acd"
>   principal_id       = azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment.va-auto-provisioning.identity[0].principal_id
> }
>
>
> resource "azurerm_security_center_automation" "la-exports" {
>   name                = "ExportToWorkspace"
>   location            =data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
>   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
>
>   action {
>     type              = "loganalytics"
>     resource_id       = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.myloga_workspace.id
>   }
>
>   source {
>     event_source = "Alerts"
>     rule_set {
>       rule {
>         property_path  = "Severity"
>         operator       = "Equals"
>         expected_value = "High"
>         property_type  = "String"
>       }
>       rule {
>         property_path  = "Severity"
>         operator       = "Equals"
>         expected_value = "Medium"
>         property_type  = "String"
>       }
>     }
>   }
>
>   source {
>     event_source = "SecureScores"
>   }
>
>   source {
>     event_source = "SecureScoreControls"
>   }
>
>   scopes = [ data.azurerm_subscription.current.id ]
> }
> ```

**Note:**
***When you enable automatic deployment, Defender for Endpoint for Linux installation will abort on machines with pre-existing running services***

Along with that Check the  [possible resolutions VMExtensionProvisioningError| Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/vm-extension-provisioning-errors)

[image]

**Reference**: [Enable the Integration | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/integration-defender-for-endpoint#linux)

Comment: Thank you. In fact I had come across the following link earlier where Liana provides the step by by instruction as well: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-cloud/deploy-microsoft-defender-for-cloud-via-terraform/ba-p/3563710. My question was whether these steps would auto deploy ms defender in Linux marketplace images? The confusing part to me is that there is an  Microsoft.Azure.AzureDefenderForServers extension of type "MDE.Linux" available and whether we need to install this extension before enabling backend services.

Answer (score 0):

This extension should only be installed for MDC Defender for Servers customers. The above instructions provided by kavyaS turn it on, and explain how to turn on the auto-provisioning settings of MDE extension. Note that there are 2 other settings that should be turned on as well (Linux, and Unified Agent for Windows Server 2012R2 and 2016)